# Xcode, Objective C, IOS. Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT". What have i done wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, syntax-error

I continue to get this problem in my application even when i added all of the frameworks and code to another Xcode app. It happens even before the view loads.

this is my error message:

```
[Switching to process 11523 thread 0x2d03]
[Switching to process 11523 thread 0x2d03]
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
warning: No copy of dns.so found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
2012-04-17 09:33:30.166 Little Birds! - iPhone[7445:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x1129f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key HighScoresPodium.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x35f08c7b __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30186ee8 objc_exception_throw + 40
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x35f08a01 -[NSException dealloc] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x34018bbf -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 186
    4   Foundation                          0x34018051 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 92
    5   Foundation                          0x34019ef3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 178
    6   Foundation                          0x33fcb805 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 144
    7   UIKit                               0x33aacf20 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 96
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x35ea9a8b -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:] + 18
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x35eb273b -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 366
    10  UIKit                               0x33aab7a0 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 868
    11  UIKit                               0x33aad640 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 140
    12  UIKit                               0x3386cb18 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 144
    13  UIKit                               0x338669ec -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 256
    14  UIKit                               0x338202e4 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1476
    15  UIKit                               0x3381fb1c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
    16  UIKit                               0x3381f3b4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6824
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x35262c88 PurpleEventCallback + 1048
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x35e9a5cb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x35e9a589 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 164
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c835 __CFRunLoopRun + 580
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c50b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 226
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c419 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 60
    23  UIKit                               0x33865554 -[UIApplication _run] + 548
    24  UIKit                               0x33862558 UIApplicationMain + 972
    25  Little Birds! - iPhone              0x0000248f main + 106
    26  Little Birds! - iPhone              0x00002420 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
(gdb)
```

Comment: can you plz post the code snippet where you call [.. setValue: forKey: ] ?

Comment: setValue: forKey: is often called by the system as it is handling variables.  You probably are not calling it explicitly anywhere.

Comment: NSString *nssHighscore3 = [myDict3 objectForKey:@"Highscore3"];    this is the only thing i could find in my code with forKey

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a dead outlet connection to me. An object in a XIB is connected to an outlet that has been deleted from the owner class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check all connection in interface builder for XIB? try with recreating XIB. I found issue when by mistake i delete a label from IB and call setText on label.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is around "HighScoresPodium".  You may have mis-assigned something to that variable.  Check for where you would be interacting with that property and you should be close to the problem.  AS others have said, the problem may be hiding out in the XIB connections.